# Debug output within a launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I enable debugging output (ROS_DEBUG) for a node within a launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9615/debug-output-within-a-launch-file/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-03-31

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The previous answer is incomplete. Setting `output="screen"` in the launch file will show INFO messages and above, not DEBUG output.

For that, you can set the [ROS console configuration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole#Configuration).

The `rxconsole` package allows dynamic setting and resetting of DEBUG output. The "Levels" button near the lower right corner can set each C++ logger to any level. (It has no effect on Python loggers.)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-03-31**:
Yes.  rxconsole is really what I was looking for.  Screen output seems to display everything except debug information.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-11-01**:
Can the debug information be pushed to the console or do we have to view it in rqt?

**Comment by [roboticom314](https://answers.ros.org/users/26759/roboticom314/) on 2016-11-09**:
Just set `output="screen"` in the launch file as mentioned below. I prefer rqt_console over the screen. It's much easier to filter and even pause the output.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-11-25**:
I think the ros console wiki had confusing language until I edited it just now- but to be clear there is no way to have a node launch with a specific logger level, if you want debug on to catch node start debug messages you have to go outside the launch file and edit this conf file (without going to extremes to have a launch file write DEBUG or INFO to a conf file and then load that with env, and the order of execution would probably be wrong without going to even further extremes of nested launch files)- is that right?

And there is no per-node log level capability in the conf file, just per-package?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the node definition, you can set the output to screen:
`<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">` for example. That will get the output pushed to your console.

You can also often find the information you're looking for through the [rxconsole](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxconsole) program. It's nice for separating the output from the many nodes that are launched, as well as displaying based on severity (warnings, errors, debugs).

---

Originally posted by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) with karma: 1033 on 2011-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3